# EM algorithm and AIC criteria

Tags: aic, expectation-maximization, mixture-distribution, likelihood, finite-mixture-model

I am using EM algorithm to estimate the model parameters. EM-algorithm iterates until the loglikelihood is converged.  After that, I need to compute AIC criteria. As known, AIC is a loglikelihood based model.

My question is, after the convergence of the EM-algorithm, must I use the convergence value of the loglikelihood from EM-algorithm in AIC or I must compute the log likelihood again for the estimated values of the model parameters, and then compute AIC?

For example, assume the loglikelihood converges at 190.5
the estimation of the model parameters are, $\theta_1= 0.5$, $\theta_2 = 4$.

Then, to compute the AIC, must I compute the loglikelihood for the estimated values of the model parameters or I can only use $190.5$ value as it is the convergence value of the EM-algorithm.

Any help, please?

Comment: Yes the AIC is using the maximum likelihood estimator as a plug-in, that is, the value of the likelihood at its maximum. One or the other, it should give your the same numerical value.

Comment: @Xi'an Thank you so much for your comment. Yes, the gave me very similar numerical value but not exactly the same. I wonder why they are quite different?

Comment: On one hand you have the expected likelihood with unobservable components, and on the other hand you have the likelihood with only observable components. The likelihood should be used with AIC, not the expected likelihood. Maybe that's where the difference is coming from.

Comment: @CowboyTrader Thank you so much. I really learn a new thing. However, for convergence, I used the observed loglikelihood function $L(\theta) = \sum log \p_{i} f(x|\theta)$. I did not use the expected likelihood for the convergence. I think the difference comes from the round error.